# inApp purchase is not working in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am testing the application, few times back the iApp is working on simulator.
As I'm using iOS-7, XCode 5.0 so it will generating error.
Currently I dont have device ? How to resolve this problem.

Help me out ?

Comment: @apoorv- you can't test in iOS simulator, you need iOS 6 to test in simulator.

Comment: *How to resolve this problem.* Buy a device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Simulator following guide lines my Apple
1. After switching the minimum deployment target of an application from iOS 7.0 to a release prior to iOS 7.0, building and running the application may fail with the message “iOS Simulator failed to install the application.”

1. To resolve this issue go to the iOS Simulator home screen. Remove the application by clicking and holding the application icon, and then choosing to delete the application by tapping the hovering “X” button. 13917023
2. The Mac hardware keyboard may not function for iOS Simulator when first launched.
   Relaunch the simulator. 13315258
3. StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

[Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW306)

Answer (score 2):

yes it is not possible to run inApp Purchases in ios7 Simulator,you definetely need device to test in app purchase

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can do that in the iPhone iOS7 Simulator. The Simulator does not have access to the app store or iTunes but definetely you can do that in iOS6

Comment: Yaa i agree but i want to do this on iOS7 Simulator.

Comment: actually its not possible in iOS7 as i havefaced this issue before

Answer (score 1):

hey you can test you IAP in simulator for testing IAP use real device instead of Simulator

chek this [link](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?threadid=176871)